# Web Crawler Java

Tags: java, parsing, web-crawler, wunderground

...

```
public static void download() {
             try {
                 URL oracle = new URL("http://api.wunderground.com/api/54f05b23fd8fd4b0/geolookup/conditions/forecast/q/US/CO/Denver.json");
                 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));

                 File file = new File("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\test2.json");
                 if (!file.exists()) {
                     file.createNewFile();
                 }
                 FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
             BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

                 String inputLine;
                 while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                     bw.write(inputLine+"\n");
                 }
                 fw.close();
                 in.close();
                 System.out.println("Finished...");
             }
             catch(MalformedURLException e){e.printStackTrace();}
             catch(IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
         }
```

I'm making a web-crawler to retrieve weather updates from Wunderground. I did get this to work, but it doesn't parse the entire document (cuts of the last bit). What did I do wrong?

Comment: Better close your `bw`.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut yep got it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrapping your `FileWriter` with a `BufferedWriter`

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
```

but only closing the `FileWriter`

```
fw.close();
```

Since the `FileWriter` doesn't have access and doesn't know about the `BufferedWriter`, it won't flush any possible remaining buffer. You could either call `flush()` on `bw` or close `bw` instead of `fw`. Calling `bw.close()` will take care of closing the wrapped `FileWriter`.

```
bw.close();
in.close();
```

Comment: Thank you, kinda figured it out from your other comments but thanks :)